# How to write an approximate url in PHP

Tags: php

I am making an glossary app in vanilla PHP (no framework) which lists various IT terms and their meaning. In the detail view of each term I would like to have a link to the relevant page in W3Schools about the selected topic, for instance if the topic is CSS, the link would be to https://www.w3schools.com/css/. Unfortunately, not all links in W3Schools follow this structure, for instance AJAX is under https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp.
I am trying to pass this url to the view in a dynamic way based on the term as follows:

```php
<p>Read more about <span class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold"><?= $model->term; ?></span> on the <a class="link" href="https://www.w3schools.com/<?= $model->term; ?>" target="_blank">W3Schools</a> website.</p>
```

Because of the problem discussed above (the links not always following the same structure) I either need to write a more approximate url in the `aù tag or make a function in my controller that allows me to replace the url with another one when it returns a 404 response. The alternative url would be one which simply contains the term somewhere in the url (see AJAX example).

Comment: Since this is a glossary - simply put the right URL as a property of the term. Then you won't need to compute it from the term.

Comment: Best solution is just use slash "/" before any url link like `<a href="/link_to_another_file">CLICK HERE</a>` basicaly slash character before any url order browesers to visit url by base of your website.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "approximate" URL. It either works or it doesn't. Simply map each term in your database to the correct URL. as it's a glossary, you presumably have a fixed, pre-defined list of terms. Unfortunately if the site you want to link to doesn't follow a consistent pattern for their URLs then you can't use rule-based code to dynamically derive the URL. You'll just need entries in your database. P.s. W3schools is not a well-regarded learning resource by most experienced IT people though. It often contains mistakes, poor practice or out of date info, unfortunately.

Comment: @ThHChauhan you've completely misunderstood the question

Comment: @ADyson it is just a personal project to practice PHP so picking W3Schools was an arbitrary choice, I do not endorse it in any way or claim it is the most reputable source.

Comment: But OK, this was a quite obvious choice to include a link when including the new entries. So far my form only had a term and a definition so I will just add an input field to the form and a column to the DB table.